# Angularjs with $sce.trustAsHtml not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm filling the contents of a  element using data retrieved from the DB. This is done within the controller of the page.
The HTML simply looks like:

```
  <select class="form-control" id="maxsize" style="width:50px">

     {{List_of_Possible_Sizes}}

  </select>
```

Within the controller, the string "List_of_Possible_Sizes" is properly built (I know because I replaced the {{...}} with the result of the JS and got the correct result), but when looking at the elements within the browser I see complete string generated from the JS as an actual string (i.e. something like:

```
 " 
   <option value.....</option><option....>...."
```

and this in spite of the fact that the assignment is:

List_of_Possible_Sizes = $sce.trustAsHtml(MyString);

Any clues you can suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Including your controller code would be a bit helpful.  Have you considered using ng-repeat to spit out your options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put the string inside curly braces `<select>{{some html}}</select>` it will be displayed as literal string.

Instead you need to use the `ng-bind-html` attribute for displaying html.

```
<select ng-bind-html="your html"></select>
```

Note: this will only work with trusted html.

Answer (score 0):

For your `<select>` I would approach it one of two ways, both are in this snippet:

```
  <div ng-controller="myController">
    <select class="form-control" id="maxsize" style="width:50px">
      <option ng-repeat="size in sizes" value="size">{{size}}</option>  
    </select>

   <select ng-options="size as size for size in sizes" ng-model="selected"></select>
  </div>
```

The controller for this example is:

```
angular.module('app', [])
        .controller('myController', function($scope){
          $scope.sizes = ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'];
        });
```

Where sizes comes from is irrelevant, could be static as here or fed through a services talking to a db.  This is just to demonstrate the multiple ways to output your `<select>`